# Minimizing and maximizing the loss

Tags: keras, autoencoder, maximize, loss

I would like to train an autoencoder in such a way that the reconstruction error will be low on some observations, and high on the others.

```
from keras.model import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import keras.backend as K

def l1Loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.abs(y_true - y_pred))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(5, input_dim=10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=l1Loss)

for i in range(1000):
    model.train_on_batch(x_good, x_good) # minimize on low
    model.train_on_batch(x_bad, x_bad, ???) # need to maximize this part, so that mse(x_bad, x_bad_reconstructed is high)
```

I saw something about replacing `???` with `sample_weight=-np.ones(batch_size)`, but I have no idea if this is fitting for my goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set sample weight to negative numbers, then minimizing it would in fact lead to maximization of its absolute value.

Comment: Is it possible to do this with the fit function instead?

Comment: Yes, you have to use the fit function's argument sample_weight. It will be harder (and slower) because you have to create an 1d numpy array and change value for each sample, depending if you want to maximize it or minimize it.